# Multiple filters javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, filter

I need to filter objects by submit form. Now when filtering I receive array of objects for each filter. And I need other scenario, after checking in the one of filter types, for example "size" (one or more), and then check "producer" its should return objects with only checked sizes. Example:
check 275-290 and then "polytech", and its returns 3 objects instead of one, that have both params.

```js
let data = [
        { id: 1, producer: ["polytech"], size: ["275-290"] },
        { id: 2, producer: ["polytech"], size: ["325-350"] },
        { id: 3, producer: ["allergan"], size: ["275-290"] },
        { id: 4, producer: ["motiva"], size: ["325-350"] },
        { id: 5, producer: ["motiva"], size: ["355-370"] },
      ]

      let filteredOutput = ""
      const form = document.querySelector("form")

      form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
        const inputs = form.querySelectorAll("input")

        let name = ""
        let value = ""
        let postArray = []

        data.forEach((post) => {
          inputs.forEach((input) => {
            if (input.checked) {
              name = input.name
              value = input.value

              if (post[name].includes(value)) {
                postArray.push(post)
              }
            }
          })
        })
        const allposts = new Set(postArray)
        filteredOutput = [...allposts]
        console.log(filteredOutput)
        console.log(filteredOutput.length)

        e.preventDefault()
      })
```

```html
<form>
      <div class="faq-body filter_buttons">
        <input type="checkbox" name="producer" value="allergan" id="allergan" />
        <label for="allergan">allergan</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="producer" value="polytech" id="polytech" />
        <label for="polytech">polytech</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="producer" value="motiva" id="motiva" />
        <label for="motiva">motiva</label>
      </div>
      <div class="faq-body filter_buttons">
        <input type="checkbox" name="size" value="275-290" id="275-290" />
        <label for="275-290">275-290</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="size" value="295-320" id="295-320" />
        <label for="295-320">295-320</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="size" value="325-350" id="325-350" />
        <label for="325-350">325-350</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="size" value="355-370" id="355-370" />
        <label for="355-370">355-370</label>

      </div>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally this code makes what you expect

```js
let data = [
        { id: 1, producer: ["polytech"], size: ["275-290"] },
        { id: 2, producer: ["polytech"], size: ["325-350"] },
        { id: 3, producer: ["allergan"], size: ["275-290"] },
        { id: 4, producer: ["motiva"], size: ["325-350"] },
        { id: 5, producer: ["motiva"], size: ["355-370"] },
      ]

const form = document.querySelector("form")

form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {

  var producer = document.getElementsByName('producer');
  var size = document.getElementsByName('size');

  let check1 = [];
  let check2 = [];

  for(var i = 0; i < producer.length; i++){
    if(producer[i].checked){
      check1.push(producer[i].value);
    }
  }
  for(var i = 0; i < size.length; i++){
    if(size[i].checked){
      check2.push(size[i].value);
    }
  }

let result = data.filter(({producer, size}) => producer.some(item => check1.includes(item))
                                            || size.some(size => check2.includes(size)));

console.log(result);
e.preventDefault()
return result;
});
```

```html
  <form>
    <div class="faq-body filter_buttons">
      <input type="checkbox" name="producer" value="allergan" id="allergan" />
      <label for="allergan">allergan</label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="producer" value="polytech" id="polytech" />
      <label for="polytech">polytech</label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="producer" value="motiva" id="motiva" />
      <label for="motiva">motiva</label>
    </div>
    <div class="faq-body filter_buttons">
      <input type="checkbox" name="size" value="275-290" id="275-290" />
      <label for="275-290">275-290</label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="size" value="295-320" id="295-320" />
      <label for="295-320">295-320</label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="size" value="325-350" id="325-350" />
      <label for="325-350">325-350</label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="size" value="355-370" id="355-370" />
      <label for="355-370">355-370</label>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </form>
```

Comment: First variant gives an error. And I can't use radiobuttons because I need multiple choiches. "Producer" and "size" just only for example, there are 8 categories of checkboxes

Comment: what do you mean 'first variant'?. With checkboxes its working too, if there are no match with data then you'll get an empty array

Comment: Yes, Its about checkboxes. Its give eror "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined at HTMLFormElement."

Comment: console log the values of checkedProducer and checkedSize, if you select for example two producer items, what output are you expecting in that case? Maybe the problem is filter by index 0 of each array, you can solve with a map method.

Comment: When I check two producers I expecting objects with this two producers, and if I check two producers and one size I expecting two producers that have this size. The same if i check two sizes and then one producer I expecting this two sizes with only one producer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217280/discussion-between-sonetlumiere-and-stasonn-l).